# Am I going mad XCTAssetNotNil(nil as String?) passes

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctest

If I run the following test I get a "Test succeeded message". How can this be so.

```
import XCTest

class MyTests: XCTestCase {

    func testATestThatMustFail() {
        XCTAssertNotNil(nil as String?)
        XCTAssertNil(nil as String?)
    }
}
```

I think I am going mad but I'm following an apple example and have reduced it to the point of insanity. Is this just a way of making it easy for developers to go home early as all tests always pass?

Comment: try `nil as? String`

Comment: XCTAssertNotNil(nil as String?) fails as expected for me. Are you sure the test is running?

Comment: XCTAssertNotNil(nil as String?) does not compile